# Auto Chat Invite after customer accepts Chat

Tags: liveagent

I have unchecked the following setting on the Auto chat invite button – “Allow invitation to be triggered again after accepting”
What is happening because of this is that chat is not being triggered again at all after first time user accepts chat.
I understand that it is not supposed to be triggered with a page refresh, however it should be triggered at-least when the user closes the browser and revisits the page, right ?

Can someone help me find out, how would a user be able to re-trigger the chat with this setting diabled ?

What if I the same user visits the web page after a couple of hours / days / weeks, would the invite pop up again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the invite will trigger again when another session is started. If you are not seeing that is most likely because your browser is not deleting the session cookie. Verify that your browser is actually deleting the cookie when the browser is closed and reopened (all tabs included) or delete the cookies manually.

Comment: Thanks for the response PepeFloyd. My next question would be how do i tell the User to delete cookies after their session ? I can do this on my end to test the development, but I cannot tell the visitor on the web page to clear cookies before they visit next time so that the chat can pop up again for them.

Comment: Is not about you telling the user, the point I was trying to make is that it seems like an issue with your browser. That feature works fine for me after I closed all tabs and start a different session.

Comment: Thanks PepeFloyd, I will talk to the web team to find out why the browser is not deleting session cookies.